# Mod Adblock detector on Joomla does not work

Tags: templates, joomla, adblock

I install the Adblock detector module on Joomla purity 3 and other detection modules Adblock, but none work then I use all the position of the template. Can you help me ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this module works. The module has no reviews and no ratings whatsoever on the JED. In any case, if the module does work but is not working on your website, then most likely you are running into some JavaScript conflicts. Just load the website in Chrome and check the console for any JavaScript errors and you will find your error right there. Again, I am assuming with my answer that the extension does work.